# Why does nslookup give me NXDOMAIN in this case?

Tags: dns, bind

I'm configuring a DNS in Fedora.

I have the zone file:

```
    $TTL 86400
    $ORIGIN example.com.
    @ IN SOA ns.example.com. root.example.com(
    2013121201 ;Serial
    28800         ;Refresh
    15         ;retry
    1w         ;expire
    3h)        ;minimum

    IN NS ns.example.com. ;in the domain
    IN NS ns2.example.com.
    IN MX 1 mail.example.com. ;mail server

    ;server host definitions
    ns      IN A 192.168.1.3 ;name server definition 
    mail    IN A 192.168.1.3

    ;non server domain hosts
    openmediavault  IN A 192.168.1.5
    ns2             IN A 192.168.1.5
```

When i do a `nslooup ns2.example.com` i get:

```
[root@SRD-GrupoG-Server etc]# nslookup ns2.example.com
Server:     192.168.1.3
Address:    192.168.1.3#53

** server can't find ns2.example.com: NXDOMAIN
```

For some reason, when i do `nslookup ns.example.com` and `nslookup openmediavault.example.com` it works fine, but for `ns2` and `mail` it gives `NXDOMAIN`

My `/etc/resolv.conf` has the correct nameserver.

```
search xxx.xxx.xxx.pt
nameserver 192.168.1.3
```

My `named.conf` file

```
zone "example.com" IN {
    type master;
    file "db.asr";
};

zone "1.168.192.in-addr.arpa" IN{
     type master;
     file "db.192.168.1";
};
```

Why isn't `nslookup ns2.example.com` working?

Thanks for your help!

**Solution**

For some reason, the files of the zone were in the wrong directory, different from the one declared in `named.conf`  and i have changed the wrong files. So that was why it cannot find the server because `ns2.example.com` didn't exist in the old ones.

Comment: Did you `rndc reload` after changing the BIND configuration? Also, your zone file looks at a glance malformed, but that should give you SERVFAIL, not NXDOMAIN. Fix that first by making sure BIND knows about your zone at all and is looking at the zone file in the first place. Also, make friends with `dig` (it's a lot more useful than `nslookup` for debugging DNS issues).

Comment: This is for a college work and my teacher gave that zone file structure and we had to adapt it. I may `dig ns2.example.com` and it also gave me `NXDOMAIN`.But it gave me a correct answer for `dig openmediavault.example.com`. Also did the `rndc reload` as suggested.

Comment: Check your logs. Turn on as much logging as you need, including query logging if required. Make *sure* that you are looking where you believe that you are looking.

Comment: I'm so sorry, is the first time i'm working with dns. How to i turn on logging and check the logs? So sorry for the trouble

Comment: Make friends with your search engine of choice. Part of the exercise is almost certainly to learn to search for information, because nothing works just the way you want it right out of the proverbial box (at least not until you have plenty of experience with the software and technologies involved). Here's another hint for you: *deliberately introduced errors can be a great debugging aid.*

Comment: In that case, please do describe the solution in a self-answer, for the benefit of those who may come across this question in the future. I would also recommend including what you learned from these comments, in case the comments get deleted.

Comment: By editing into the question, others can't benefit. Post as an answer, not part of the question